# Connect NVIDIA RTX 6000 with 2 ATX 6000 Cards with Bridge

Tags: graphics-cards, nvidia

I would like to get a information. I have currently on my PC a Quadro RTX 6000. I would like to buy 2 new cards A6000. Is there a way to have 2 bridges which would allow to connect the 3 cards (1 RTX 6000 and 2 A6000) ?

Or maybe is there a software way to do computations on the 3 cards in the same time ?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://www.amazon.com/dp/B084TPJR7P/

Comment: @Salocor . I don't know if this the right piece, I don't see the trademark NVIDIA on this. Could you add more precisions ? Is it located at the back of the PC or in front of ? Moreover, maybe is there a software way to aggregate the 3 cards ? Regards

Comment: Yeah this is the part you need.  It would connect at the top of the GPU.  I just looked, and you would need 3 of the same graphics cards in order to use SLI, so you can disregard my previous comment.  Forgot about that, sorry.  As for a software method, I’m not 100% sure, but I think you can just plug the three cards in and assign different tasks to different cards.  If someone reads this and realizes I’m wrong, please correct me :).

Comment: @Salocor Another issue is that these cards cannot fit an SLI bridge, you would need an NVlink  connector.